# changing user home directory has no effect

Tags: bash, sudo, users, home

When I switch from root user to a user (automatically created when installing [git-auto-deploy](https://github.com/olipo186/Git-Auto-Deploy)) with

`sudo -u git-auto-deploy /bin/bash` I always get this error:

> bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied

I created a user home directory, and put a `.profile` in it with the following (ran `source` on it too):

```
export HOME=/srv/users/git-auto-deploy
```

The command `finger git-auto-deploy` gives the following output:

```
Login: git-auto-deploy                  Name:
Directory: /srv/users/git-auto-deploy   Shell: /bin/bash
Never logged in.
```

When logged in as this user, the `env` command still lists incorrect directory:

```
HOME=/root
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you add `-l` option to your `sudo`?

Comment: No, it just outputs `/bin/bash`, doesn't even do the user switch.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `sudo -s -H -u git-auto-deploy`.

`sudo` by itself does not change the value of `HOME`, but does so when `-H` is used. This is why you're getting that "Permission denied" error. The user can't access `root`'s home directory (and shouldn't be able to either).

The `-s` option makes `sudo` start whatever shell is configured as the login shell for the specified user (i.e. no need to explicitly run `/bin/bash`).

Comment: Makes sense, only `sudo -s -H` executes the `git-auto-deploy` service, it doesn't perform a user switch.

Comment: @montrealist see updated answer. There was a missing option.